# Altering existing jquery script for Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Bit stuck on the correct way to call the right action for this.
The existing script.js fades the span color on mouseover, but I would also like it to show the associated thumbnail text and link on mouse over

The code from WP to display the thumbnail title & link

```
<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
```

and the existing script file

```
  $('.thumb img').after('<span></span>');
    $('.thumb span').css('opacity','0');
    $('.post_home a:first-child').hover(function(){
        $(this).find('span').stop().animate({opacity: 0.95}, 200);
        $(this).nextAll().find('a').css('color', '#ff0000');
    }, function(){
        $(this).find('span').stop().animate({opacity: 0}, 200);
        $(this).nextAll().find('a').removeAttr('style');
    });
```

Any help would be TERRIFIC!
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If this is the only <h2> with an anchor tag in it on the page, then I would add the jquery hide() and show() methods to the script:

```
$('.thumb img').after('<span></span>');
$('.thumb span').css('opacity','0');
$('.post_home a:first-child').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('span').stop().animate({opacity: 0.95}, 200);
    $(this).nextAll().find('a').css('color', '#ff0000');
    $('h2 a').show();
}, function(){
    $(this).find('span').stop().animate({opacity: 0}, 200);
    $(this).nextAll().find('a').removeAttr('style');
    $('h2 a').hide();
});
```

Comment: but if the <h2><a> tag relationship is not unique to the page, then you may want to peruse the various jQuery selectors in order to locate it in relation to the $('.post_home a:first-child') element.  The jQuery selector list can be found here: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/